# Install Ubuntu using USB on hp 14-dk0xxx win10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I need help installing Ubuntu via USB. I changed the bios and it still loaded up with my regular desktop (I'm not a techy so may use different wording). I disabled the legacy & secure boot and that didn't work. When I normally boot up my laptop I have a pin screen and wonder if this is why the USB doesn't boot, even though I changed the boot order multiple times. So far nothing has worked for me. I'm using a hp laptop 14-dk0xxx. Thank you!

Comment: How did you made the USB installer?

Comment: In my experience (writing hundreds of ISOs to thumb-drive per annum) you should start at basics. We don't know what release, if you validated your ISO as valid before writing (ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then verified the write to your install media (in my experience this is a semi-common failure; with 5-8% of writes failing; but how to verify depends on your *unstated* release so do as appropriate for your *unstated* Ubuntu product; we don't know server? desktop? other? and what release of each etc)

Answer (score 4):

According to [page 74 of the service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06242992.pdf), you’ll need to follow these steps:

1. Insert the USB media
2. Start the computer and access the system Startup menu by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to interrupt the BIOS, then <kbd>F9</kbd> to select a boot device
3. Choose the USB stick

So long as the USB device is bootable, it should appear in the list

Comment: This is applicable to all UEFI based HP models since at least 2012-13.

Comment: Thank you, matigo, this was very helpful. I'm sick and haven't yet been able to finish the process. I may have more questions once I'm better and able to get back to this.

Comment: Thank you, changanauto, I had to select ueif to get to the usb drive but didn't see ubuntu tho my laptop says it's there. I think it's cuz it's on 2 drives (I initially installed it on my laptop). When I'm feeling better I'll return to this.